# Can't resolve "Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1" error when building Flutter Android app in VSCode

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, gradle

After switching to Flutter 3.10.6 I keep receiving below error which seems to be caused by missing Gradle 8.2.1.
I've changed the Gradle and Kotlin version numbers in **build.gradle** and graddle-**wrapper.properties** but had this 8.2.1. related error regadless.

Another thing worth mentioning is the Android SDK version **30.0.3** which allegedly does not support API level **31** I'm targeting with my app.

```
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.1/gradle-8.2.1.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.1/gradle-8.2.1.pom
Required by:
    project :
```

Flutter doctor output

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.3086], locale et-EE)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.4)   
[√] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[√] Android Studio
[√] VS Code (version 1.81.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

Gradle -v output

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-07-10 12:12:35 UTC
Revision:     a38ec64d3c4612da9083cc506a1ccb212afeecaa      

Kotlin:       1.8.20
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          19.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 19.0.2+7-44)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }        
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

graddle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2.1-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

C:\Users\pavel>path

```
PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Program Files\Puppet Labs\Puppet\bin;
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IDEMIA\AWP\Dlls;
C:\Program Files\IDEMIA\AWP\Dlls;
C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Sync\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Migration\;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;
C:\Users\pavel\AppData\Roaming\nvm;
C:\Program Files\nodejs;
c:\flutter\bin;
C:\Users\pavel\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache;
C:\Users\pavel\AppData\Roaming\nvm;
C:\Program Files\nodejs;
C:\Users\pavel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
C:\Users\PavelMurnikov_AD_Account\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;
C:\Users\pavel\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;
c:\php;
C:\Gradle\gradle-8.2.1\bin;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it by changing the Gradle version to lower , I think 8.2.1 is not stable yet .

**try** changing the version in file : android/gradle/gradle-warpper.properties
to :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

and change version on file : android/build.gradle to :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
```

then try it after runing : flutter clean

Answer (score 2):

What is your Java version? Gradle 8.2 requires Java 11 or higher. If you are using lower version then download Java 11+ and set JAVA_HOME:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/jdk-21.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

1. I set AGP 8.2.0
2. I set gradle version.
3. The only cause was I set default JDK for Android Studio was JAVA_1_8, but for gradle 8.+ we need to setup at lease JAVA_17. (Setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK -> JDK 17)

If you use Visual Studio:

/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file edit:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip`

then, edit /app/build.gradle file:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0'`

If you use Android Studio:
Setting:
[image]

Project Structure:
[image]

Comment: Which Android studio version did you use for AGP 8.2?

Comment: I used Android Studio Hedgehog. There is not restriction for latest (v8.7), you may use v8.2 in any Android Studio version